# How to skip top header and bottom header with Tidyverse tools such as dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to learn skipping the top header and the bottom header in tidyverse tools.

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa;;;
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa;;;
;aaaaa(%);;
;aaaaaaaaaa;aaaaaaaaaaaaa;

 aa/33;3.3;3.3;
 a/33;3.3;3.3;
aa/33;3.3;33.3;
 a/33;3.3;33.3;
 aa/33;3.3;33.3;
 a/33;3.3;33.3;
aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aa
aaaaaaa: %
aaaaa: aaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa / aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aa;;;
```

There are 5 rows long top header at the start while the end has 3 rows long bottom header.

**How can I skip them with Tidyverse tools in R?**

Comment: What is the file type?  If it is excel, then `df1 <- read_excel(yourfile.xlsx", skip=5, n_max = 6)`

Comment: @akrun csv where separator is the semicolon `;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use `read_delim`

```
library(readr)
df1 <- read_delim("fileN.csv", skip=5, n_max = 6, delim= ";", col_names = FALSE)
```

There is an extra `;` at the end.  So, either it could be removed earlier or remove the column of NA afterwards

```
Filter(function(x) !all(is.na(x)), df1)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#     X1    X2    X3
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  aa/33   3.3   3.3
#2   a/33   3.3   3.3
#3  aa/33   3.3  33.3
#4   a/33   3.3  33.3
#5  aa/33   3.3  33.3
#6   a/33   3.3  33.3
```

To make it more dynamic, we can specify the `n_max` from `count.fields`

```
df1 <- read_delim("fileN.csv", skip=5, n_max = length(count.fields("fileN.csv"))-(5+2),
                           delim= ";", col_names = FALSE)
```

Comment: I think `Filter(function(x) all(!is.na(x)), df1)` should be `Filter(function(x) !all(is.na(x)), df1)` ..?